# How do I display the row number for pandas dataframe while using groupby?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with results using groupby.  I want the output to display a row number for the output that I can use for reference

```
df.groupby("Class").agg({"Avg. B. Ranking": np.mean,"Class": np.size}).sort_values("Avg. B. Ranking",ascending=True)

Avg. B. Ranking  Class
Class                         
AN2X          2.000000      1
AN3L          2.250000      4
```

So it would output a relative row number i.e.

```
Avg. B. Ranking  Class
Class                         
1.   AN2X          2.000000      1
2.   AN3L          2.250000      4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `as_index` parameter in `groupby()` method

By default `as_index` parameter in `groupby()` is `True` so make it `False`

Use this:-

```
df.groupby("Class",as_index=False).agg({"Avg. B. Ranking": np.mean,"Class": np.size}).sort_values("Avg. B. Ranking",ascending=True)
```

Comment: Using the additional comment below this sorted the index values df.groupby("Class",as_index=False).agg({"Max B. Ranking": np.mean}).sort_values("Max B. Ranking",ascending=True).reset_index()

Answer (score 1):

Anurag's answer is correct, but there is something implied in your example that is not addressed. If I understand you correctly, you want to assign the row number *after* the ranking is sorted. To do that you can omit `as_index`, and add `.reset_index() to the end.

```
 result = df.groupby("Class").agg({"Avg. B. Ranking": np.mean,"Class": np.size}).sort_values("Avg. B. Ranking",ascending=True).reset_index()
```

Also implied by the example, you want your index to start with 1 not 0. To do this efficiently, you can call the line of code:

```
 result.index = result.index+1
```

Comment: This was essentially correct with this addition, however I had to drop the aggregation of Class since it produced the error for the Class column ValueError: cannot insert Class, already exists
The acceptable solution is df.groupby("Class",as_index=False).agg({"Max B. Ranking": np.mean}).sort_values("Max B. Ranking",ascending=True).reset_index()